# Unable to update a getstream activity created from json

Tags: android, json, getstream-io, gson

If we update an activity after retrieving from stream, we are able to update

```
String feedId = "ef202000-3f6b-11e7-8080-800171e94936";
Feed feed = StreamUtils.getStreamClient().newFeed(Constants.FEED_SLUG, "feed_66_103");
NotificationActivityServiceImpl<MessageItem> userMessagesActivityService = feed.newNotificationActivityService(MessageItem.class);
FeedFilter filter = new FeedFilter.Builder().withIdGreaterThanEquals(feedId).withLimit(1).build();
StreamResponse<NotificationActivity<MessageItem>> userMessageItems = userMessagesActivityService.getActivities(filter, false, false);
if (userMessageItems != null && userMessageItems.getResults().size() != 0) {
    for (NotificationActivity<MessageItem> messageItemNotificationActivity : userMessageItems.getResults()) {
        for (MessageItem messageItem : messageItemNotificationActivity.getActivities()) {
            messageItem.setMessage_status(MESSAGE_STATUS_READ);
            userMessagesActivityService.updateActivities(Collections.singletonList(messageItem));
            Log.d("Message json", new Gson().toJson(messageItem));
        }
    }
}
```

But, If we update it by constructing the activity, we are unable to update

```
Feed feed = StreamUtils.getStreamClient().newFeed(Constants.FEED_SLUG, "chat_66_103");
String messageJson = "{\"channel_id\":\"feed_66_103\",\"message\":{\"message_text\":\"Test message\"},\"message_status\":\"DELIVERED\",\"receivers\":[103],\"actor\":\"66\",\"foreignId\":\"66_103_1495511846405\",\"id\":\"ef202000-3f6b-11e7-8080-800171e94936\",\"object\":\"delivery_message\",\"time\":\"May 23, 2017 9:27:26 AM\",\"to\":[],\"verb\":\"delivery_message\"}";
MessageItem messageItem = new Gson().fromJson(messageJson, MessageItem.class);
messageItem.setMessage_status(MESSAGE_STATUS_READ);
NotificationActivityServiceImpl<MessageItem> userMessagesActivityService = feed.newNotificationActivityService(MessageItem.class);
userMessagesActivityService.updateActivities(Collections.singletonList(messageItem));
Log.d("Message json", new Gson().toJson(messageItem));
```

In the setMessage_status method, I'm changing values of variables object, verb, message_status

Here even the logs printing the same object. We don't know what we are missing.

We tried it from python client as well. Same issue there as well.

Comment: You can't update time or foreign_id fields

Comment: I did few trails to test weather i'm able to update or not. And forget to remove that line while posting the question.. It's not working though i'm not updating time

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli Can you try it please?

Answer (score 0):

Updating activities is done using your foreign ID. Currently your payload is sending this value in a field called `foreignId` and our endpoint will be expecting `foreign_id`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But as for BaseActivity model, while serializing json to java model, It assigning foreignId value to foreign_id.. Even I'm able to log and access it from java model. Below is the snippet present in BaseActivity

@JsonProperty("foreign_id")
protected String foreignId;

Even I set the foreignId using setForeignId method, but still unable to update.

Comment: Okay, your code didn't present that. The last line of your code dumps the JSON, can you add that to your original question so we can see it too? `Log.d("Message json", new Gson().toJson(messageItem));`

Comment: Also, our SDKs would usually return a payload of data from an update call, like your call here. Could you check for a return value and add that to your question as well? `userMessagesActivityService.updateActivities(Collections.singletonList(messageItem));`